# Active Directory Folder Effective Permissions of all users

Tags: active-directory, directory, user-permissions

I know that is easy to get the effective permissions of one group or user over a folder, but I want to know if it is possible to get the effective permissions for all users on my shared folder. There is any tool to do that?

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that'll list every person with access and what access they get?

Comment: yes, or a windows command if exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in GUI dialog for Security in Explorer will show all explicit and inherited permissions on a file or directory. If a user isn't listed, either by name or by group membership, they have no rights. There's no "effective rights" dialog that I'm aware of, if you're used to and coming from a Netware environment. And you probably wouldn't want a dialog to automatically expand group memberships, since you can have things like "domain users", which would take a while to enumerate in a large domain.

/edit - of course, there's the "effective rights" tab in modern Windows, for a given user or group. Jeez, losing my mind. My point about enumerating "all users" stands - that would take a long time in a large domain, and probably be awful in a large forest.

Comment: An ugly idea, trying to enumerate the "effective permissions" of a large number of users on even a single resource. Every time I've been asked about reporting on effective permissions for large groups of users I've always found that the issue at the kernel of the request is one of lack of centralized control and design of permission hierarchies. I wouldn't be surprised if that's at play here.

Comment: Well, my domain is very simple, only 50 users on a single domain controller and the files are on same server, I think that in this case could be faster than one more complex.

Comment: @EvanAnderson Good points, but consider the strict auditing policies of outside agencies coming in and demanding a report. Even if you have centralized control and well designed permission hierarchies, to audit the permissions one must connect the dots of user->group->permissions * # resources * # users. Auditors often do not go for the let-me-explain-how-I'm-doing-things-the-right-way-and-you-take-my-word-that-no-one-has-permissions-they-shouldn't. I know some have custom tools that randomly select resource+user to review select permissions, which avoids enumerating the entire system.

Comment: @AaronLS - any audit taking place is in the context of what's in-scope for the audit. The companies that I've worked for, going through such audits, will show the ACLs on the folders or files that fall under the scope. The companies work hard to limit and define what's in-scope.

Comment: @mfinni Many audits will include a spot checking of actual permissions to be within the scope of the audit.  If they are doing their job right, then they won't interested in acl's, because that makes alot of possibly invalid assumptions about people only being in the groups they should be(which is often not the case) and thus should be looking at actual effective permissions.

Comment: @AaronLS - I've been on both sides of that type of auditing situation (being audited and being the auditor) and I've never seen or produced a report describing all resources and effective permissions for all users. How would the mechanics of such a report in an environment of any appreciable size work? I could live with a control that requires an audit trail of resource permission changes and user group membership changes, personally. The effective permission for a user to any resource at a point-in-time could be calculated from that audit trail.

Comment: @EvanAnderson "I've never seen or produced a report describing all resources and effective permissions for all users" You clearly didn't read even my first comment clearly, because I gave a very specific example of exactly how you would audit permissions **without** having to list every single resource and user.  We can't continue this conversation effectively if you aren't going to exercise even the most basic of reading comprehension skills.

Comment: @EvanAnderson "some have custom tools that randomly select resource+user to review select permissions, which avoids enumerating the entire system" since you glazed completely over that.  And I'm done now.

Comment: @AaronLS - The hostility you're showing adds nothing to the conversation, and I certainly don't care to argue with you if you're going to be like that. I'll be "done now", too.

Comment: @EvanAnderson The feeling is mutual. There is no hostility intended there, it's simply a fact of how you approached the conversation as if I had said things I did not say, and it comes together to form a situation that is unproductive. When people don't exercise reading comprehension, then the argument goes around in circles, and when you demonstrated such, I chose to bow out.

Comment: @AaronLS - Against my better judgement I'd sincerely like to talk to you about this. I don't get where you're attacking my reading comprehension. Considering the amount of positive interaction I've had on this site over the last 5 years (and the volume emails I send / receive from Custoemrs every day) I'd genuinely like to understand what I'm comprehending wrong. Here's a chat link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15219/blarg

Comment: I went ahead and wrote-up what I wanted to say (which definitely wouldn't fit here) on that chat link. I'd appreciate a response but, if nothing else, I got it off my chest.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [SetACL](http://helgeklein.com/).  It is very, very powerful and our storage engineers use it to audit shares before migrating them to different boxes.  I too have used it and have to say it is pretty useful.

Here is a sample command we use to see all permissions on a share folder. You want to do it on the server itselt.

`setacl -ot file -on F:\sharedirectory -actn list -lst "f:tab;w:d;i:n;s:n" -rec cont_obj -log \path\to\logfile.txt`

Comment: I don't see how this is going to do what the OP wants. The OP is asking for the effective permissions for users. The command-line you're quoting there is going to dump the ACLs specified on the resource. The effective permissions would be based on mapping the user's group membership to the ACLs specified on the resource (just like the OS does when the user attempts to access the resource).

Answer (score 1):

The [AccessChk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922) utility from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027) is a command-line tool for viewing the effective permissions on files, registry keys, services, processes, kernel objects, and more.

Answer (score 0):

is there such a thing as an "Active Directory Folder"? I think you mean a windows folder - or an Active Directory OU or Container? If you mean Windows folders, I used to use **TreeSize** which is mostly for calculating the space of subfolders of directories but also has a security tab which will show all the effective permissions assigned to folders, subfolders and files.

http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/

Very useful utility with a decent GUI but you can script probably all of what it does on your own if you have the time.

Comment: He does explain by saying "shared folder" in his question text, so I would only read that as a directory on a filesystem that has been shared.